# Replace starting frames with a one at specified time with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm editing a video of a presentation (screencast of a slide show, so the content changes rarely). The video should be split by chapters.

The problem is that the speaker starts their talk on next chapter but for 2-3 seconds shows an old slide, or even scrolls through the slides in search of the correct one.

I would like to leave the audio as is, but replace starting frames (from 0 to 3 seconds) with the one in 3rd second of the video.

I could do it in a visual editor by splitting the channels and replacing the video, but I would like to automate it.

How can I achieve my goal with FFmpeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple* as

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf trim=X -c:a copy out.mp4
```

X is timestamp of the frame you want to clone at start. All frames from 0 to X are replaced with that frame.

*applies for output formats like MP4, where ffmpeg assumes constant frame rate. For variable frame rate muxing, like Matroska, use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf trim=X,setpts='if(eq(N,0),0,PTS)' -c:a copy out.mkv
```